# Conditional operation in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using the below code to find a certain element and extract it using the following `XPath`. But in some pages they are not available.

How should I proceed?

FYI The below code is failing.

```
String founded=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Founded')]//following::dd[1]")).getText();
if(founded.isEmpty())
{
    founded="NA";
    System.out.println(founded);
}
```

Comment: Please add any errors and/or exceptions + stacktraces you recieve to your question. If you don't tell us the exact problem we can only guess.  And my guess is that your problem is: The method findElement will throw a NoSuchElementException when it doesn't find an element (As you could have seen from reading its documentation). If you want to handle the case were no element is found you have to catch and handle that exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using [`WebElement.findElements()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-) instead which returns either list of [`WebElement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) or empty list. So just check for empty list as below :-

```
String founded = "";

List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Founded')]//following::dd[1]"));

if(list.isEmpty() || list.get(0).getText() == null || list.get(0).getText().isEmpty())
 {
   founded = "NA";
 }else {
   founded = list.get(0).getText();
 }    
 System.out.println(founded);
```